# How does the two index spinor $(v_{a\dot{b}})$ transforms?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

Using the [Van der Waerden Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden_notation), we define the [four-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector) as:

$$v_{a\dot{b}}=v_\nu \sigma^\nu_{a\dot{b}}$$

I'm trying to see how this transforms. Defining:

$$\Lambda \equiv e^{i\vec{\theta}\cdot \frac{\vec{\sigma}}{2}+\vec{\phi}\cdot \frac{\vec{\sigma}}{2}}\ \ \ \ \&\ \ \ \ \ \Gamma \equiv  e^{i\vec{\theta}\cdot \frac{\vec{\sigma}}{2}-\vec{\phi}\cdot \frac{\vec{\sigma}}{2}} $$

so that

$$\chi_L=\chi_a \rightarrow \chi_a'=\Lambda^b_a \chi_a \\
\xi_R=\xi^{\dot{a}}\rightarrow \xi'^{\dot{a}}=\Gamma^\dot{a}_\dot{b}\xi^{\dot{b}}$$

Therefore,

$$v_{a\dot{b}}\rightarrow v'_{a\dot{b}}=v_{a}^{'\dot{c}}\epsilon_{\dot{c}\dot{b}}=\Lambda^d_a v_d^{\dot{e}}\Gamma_{\dot{e}}^{\dot{c}}\epsilon_{\dot{c}\dot{b}} \\
=\Lambda^d_a v_{d\dot{f}}\epsilon^{\dot{f}\dot{e}}\Gamma_{\dot{e}}^{\dot{c}}\epsilon_{\dot{c}\dot{b}} =-\Lambda^{d}_a v_{d\dot{c}} \Gamma^{\dot{c}}_\dot{b} $$

where I used that $\epsilon^{\dot{a}\dot{b}}=-i\sigma_y$.

I'm reading '[Physics from Symmetry](http://physicsfromsymmetry.com/)' and there the author wrote -

$$v'_{a\dot{b}}= \left(e^{i\vec{\theta}\cdot \frac{\vec{\sigma}}{2}+\vec{\phi}\cdot \frac{\vec{\sigma}}{2}}\right)^c_a v_{c\dot{d}} \left(\left(e^{-i\vec{\theta}\cdot \frac{\vec{\sigma}^*}{2}+\vec{\phi}\cdot \frac{\vec{\sigma^*}}{2}}\right)^{\dot{d}}_\dot{b}\right)^T$$

I'm not sure how this comes about.

Comment: Note that $v_{\alpha\dot{\beta}}\in TM$ and for 3+1 dim manifold, you have the isomorphism $TM \~ S×S'$ where S is the spin space. For $v$ to be null vector, it follows that $v_{\alpha\dot{\beta}}=v_{\alpha}\bar{v}_{\dot{\beta}}$. For time like vector you can write $v$ as superposition of two or more null vectors

Comment: This way of doing things seems very non-standard, is there a reason the author is trying to do it this way? I prefer the formalisms developed in the classic Susy texts, like Wess & Bagger, Gates et al, Kuzenko & Buchbinder etc.

Comment: @SigmaAlpha Even the susy texts use the van der waerden symbols. The spin group corresponding to $SO^{+}(1, 3) $ is $SL(2, C) $. It is pretty standard to look at transformation of 2-spinors (square root of a null four vector) under SL(2, C) when the four vector transform under $SO^{+}(1, 3) $

Comment: @KP99 Thanks for the reply. Pardon me, But I just started with the QFT course and am not so familiar with what you are saying. Is there a simple analogy or way to understand what the author wrote?

Comment: Spinors and space-time, Vol-I by R.Penrose and W.Rindler is an excellent source for 2-spinor formalism (the first three chapters should be more than enough)

Comment: @KP99 I agree with you, I just meant that the way the author presents the 2-component formalism is non-standard and (imo) can be done in a much cleaner and elegant way.